# ASP.NET MVC Session state using state partitioning, MongoDB or Memcached or...?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, session, scalability

My team is currently building a new SaaS application for our company ([Amilia.com](http://www.amilia.com)). We are in "alpha" release and the application was built to be deployed on a web farm.

For our session provider, we are using Sql Server mode (in DEV and TEST) and it seems to be not "scalable", hence we are looking for the best solution for handling sessions in asp.net (mvc3 in our case). We are currently using Sql Server but we would like to switch to an other system due to license cost.

We target 20 000 [EDITED, was 100k before] concurrent users. In session, we store a GUID, a string and a Cart object (we try to keep it as little as possible, this object allows us to save 3 queries at each request).

Here are the different solutions I've found :

ASP.NET built-in solutions:

No session : impossible in our case (eliminated)

In-Proc Mode : can't be used in a webfarm. (eliminated)

StateServer Mode : can be used in a webfarm but if the server goes down, I lose all my sessions. (eliminated)

StateServer Mode with a PartitionResolver using multiple servers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/cc163730.aspx#S8) If I undestand well, if one of these servers goes down, only a part of my users will lose their session.

SqlServer Mode : can be used in a webfarm, if the server goes down, I can recover my sessions but the process is quite slow. Moreover, that database becomes a bottleneck in case of heavy load.

SqlServer Mode with a PartitionResolver using multiple servers (http://www.bulletproofideas.net/2011/01/true-scale-out-model-for-aspnet-session.html) : If one of these servers goes down, only a part of my users will lose their session. If the user was doing nothing between the downtime, he will recover his previous session otherwise he will be redirected to the signin screen.

Custom solutions :

Use MongoDB as Session storage (http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/05/mongodb-aspnet-session-state-store.html) It seems to be a good tradeoff but my knowledge in nosql is quite rudimentary so I cannot see the cons.

Use Memcached : the problem will be the same as StateServer mode and if the memcached server goes down, all my sessions are lost. Furthermore, I think Memcached is not dedicated to store session state ?

Use distributed memcached like ScaleOut (http://highscalability.com/product-scaleout-stateserver-memcached-steroids) : seems to be the best solution but it costs money.

Use repcached and memcached (http://repcached.lab.klab.org/), I've never seen an implementation of that solution.

We could easily go to Ms Azure and use tools provided by it but we have only one application, so if Microsoft doubles the price, we immediately double our infrastructure cost (but that's another subject).

So, what's the best way or at least what's your opinion about this ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

SQL Server session is pretty good. Since you already have a SQL Server database to store your primary data, you can just create another database and store the ASP.NET Session there.

About the scalability, I would say if you have 100,000 **concurrent** users, then your userbase must be more than 10 millions or more. You should do some practical estimate to see really how long it will take to reach such a concurrent user load. In my previous startup, we had millions of users all around the world, 24x7, but we hardly ever reached 10K concurrent users even though people used our site continuously for hours every day.

If you really have 100,000 concurrent users, license cost would be the least of your worry. With right business model, having 100K concurrent users means you have at least $10M revenue/year.

I have built myoffice.bt.com that uses SQL Server session and all primary data on a single SQL Server instance, but in two databases. Between 8 AM to 10 AM, millions of users hit our site. We hardly have any performance issue. With a dual Core server, 8 GB RAM, you can happily run a SQL Server instance and support such a load as long as you code it right. It all depends on how you have coded. If you have followed performance best practices, you can easily scale to millions of users on a single database server.

Take a look at my performance suggestions from: 
http://omaralzabir.com/tag/performance/

I have used memcached clusters only to cache frequently used data. Never used for session for good reasons. There's been several occasions where a memcached server had to be rebooted. If we had used memcached for session, we would have lost all the sessions stored in that instance. So, I would not recommend storing sessions in memcached. But then again, how important is it for your app to maintain data in session? If you have a shopping cart, then as users add products on the cart, it must get persisted in database, not in session. Session is usually for short term storage. For any transactional data, you should never keep it on session, instead store it on relational tables directly.

I am always in support of not using Session. Developers abuse session all the time. Whenever they want to pass data from one page to another, they just put it on the Session. It results in bad design. If you truly want to scale to 100K concurrent user base, design your app to not use session at all. Any transactional data must be stored in database. Cart is a transactional object and thus it's not suitable for holding on Session. At some point you would need to know how many carts get started but never gets placed. So, you will need to store them in database permanently.

Remember, database based session is nothing but databased based serialization. Think very carefully on what you are serializing into database. You will have to clean it up as well since Session_End won't fire for database based session or in fact most of the out of proc sessions. So, essentially you are giving devs ability to just serialize data into database and bypass relational model. It always results in bad coding.

With permanent relational storage, fronted by a high performance cache like memcached, you have much better design to support large user base.

Hope this helps your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very interesting. In fact, we target 5000 customers for our Platform for the next 2 years, each customer has about 300 users. For each customer, we provide a registration platform, the registration periods are generally in the same time for all of our customers (=>peeks). As the items sold are gone in less than 5 min., it's tough to estimate the number of "concurrent users". By reading you, maybe I overestimated our target. Targeting 20K concurrent users seems more reasonable. For sessions, it seems a bad to store session with Memcached.

Comment: `Between 8 AM to 10 AM, millions of users hit our site. We hardly have any performance issue. With a dual Core server, 8 GB RAM ` is that really true? :::O